# How to propogate a changing scope variable through a function in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For example, if I have the following case:

```
function ACtrl($scope) {
  $scope.title = "Title";
  $scope.funkyString= funkyAndComplexStuff($scope.title);
  function funkyAndComplexStuff(title) {
     /*...*/
     return title;   
  }
}
```

With html:

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="ACtrl">
    <div>
      {{title}} and length {{funkyString}}
        <input type="text" ng-model='title' />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like the `$scope.funkyString` to update every time `$scope.title` gets changed.

As far as I see I have 2 options:

- Using a `watch` on the variable
- Creating a filter I could apply on `$scope.funkyString`

But both of those sound unndecessarily heavy. Is there anything else I could use to post-process the data as soon as it gets changed?

EDIT:

Modified my example so that people are hopefully less confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this, so it can handle changes to $scope.title from other fields of code also

```
<div ng-controller="ACtrl">
    <div>
      {{title}} and length {{ funkyAndComplexStuff(title) }}
        <input type="text" ng-model='title' />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It is an abstract example. I don't actually need the length.

Comment: There are number of right ways to solve a problem, I was trying to solve your problem based on your given code. I really don't think it deserve a negative vote.

Comment: That was not what my post was asking. It was just a mere example. The question was and is -  Is there anything else I could use to post-process the data as soon as it gets changed?

Answer (score 2):

You could do `title.length` as @ssilas777 has suggested. You can also set the `$scope` variable to be a function. As I understand it, the function will be called during the scope's `$digest` cycle, which will fire when any bound model changes. See this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/9xspXj5ND8seEX2LNeMe?p=preview

See this HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="title" />
Num chars: <span ng-bind="numCharsInTitle()"></span>
```

and the JS:

```
$scope.title = "The Title";
$scope.numCharsInTitle = function() {
  return $scope.title.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-change` could be a simple solution depending on the element to which your `title` model is bound. If it's an input like in the example this might could work:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.title = "Title";

  $scope.funkyAndComplexStuff = function(title) {
     /*...*/
     $scope.funkyString = title.length;   
  }
});
```

...

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

     {{title}} and length {{funkyString}}
     <input type="text" ng-model='title' ng-change="funkyAndComplexStuff(title)" />

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like ssilas777 and Charlie S and you said you can use `$watch`, custom `$filter` or function in `$scope`

But for me it's complicated to maintain code with function linked to the view. I prefere using `$watch` because all the processing is in the controller and only `$scope.numberOfChars` is present in the view.

If you use this many time, I would suggest you to create a custom filter.

```js
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('ACtrl',
function ($scope) {
  $scope.title = "Title";
  getNumberChars($scope.title);
  function getNumberChars(title) {
     $scope.numberOfChars = title.length;   
  };
  
  $scope.getNumberChars = function() {
     return $scope.title.length;   
  };
  
  $scope.$watch('title',getNumberChars);
})
.filter('customFilter', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return input.length;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ACtrl">
    <div>
      {{title}} and length {{numberOfChars}} or {{title.length}} or {{getNumberChars()}} or {{title | customFilter}}
        <input type="text" ng-model='title' />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
function ACtrl($scope) {
  $scope.title = "Title";
  $scope.funkyAndComplexStuff = function () {
     /*..do stuff with $scope.title..*/
     return $scope.title; // or whatever   
  }
}
```

With html:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="ACtrl">
      <div>
        {{title}} and length     {{funkyAndComplexStuff()}}
         <input type="text" ng-model='title' />
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Not sure why somebody downvoted, but here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xhdk3f25/1/

Comment: Agree, perfectly reasonable answer.